# Symfony2 error with forms and related entities

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I have been searching before for an answer for this problem but after hours I need to ask you.

I have one Entity called Pedidos, that have another entity related called PedidosMateriales, as you can see:

```
(...)    
/**
 * Pedidos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ochodoscuatro\IntranetBundle\Entity\PedidosRepository")
 */
class Pedidos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

(...)

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PedidosMateriales", mappedBy="pedido")
    */
    private $pedidosmateriales;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->pedidosmateriales = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->pagos = new  \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addPedidosmateriales(\ochodoscuatro\IntranetBundle\Entity\PedidosMateriales $pedidosmateriales){
        $this->pedidosmateriales[] = $pedidosmateriales;
    }
    public function getPedidosmateriales(){
        return $this->pedidosmateriales;
    }



    (...)



}
```

When I submit a form, if I get $_POST, I can see all the information good there, but just after doing

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I get this error:

> Neither the property "pedidosmateriales" nor one of the methods "addPedidosmaterial()", "addPedidosmateriale()", "setPedidosmateriales()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "ochodoscuatro\IntranetBundle\Entity\Pedidos".

But I have them already written!

I've read that with "multiple" => true I could get the answer, but it launch another error telling that the option "multiple" does not exist.

My form is this:

```
$builder->add('fechapedido', 'date', array(//Fecha del pedido
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy', 
                'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'), 
                'data' => new \DateTime() //Valor (Fecha actual)
            ))
            ->add('cliente', 'entity', array( 
'class' => 'ochodoscuatroIntranetBundle:Clientes',
'property' => 'nombre',
'empty_value' => 'Nombre cliente'))//Nombre del "placeholder"
            ->add('pedidosmateriales', 'collection', array('type' => new PedidosMaterialesType(), 'allow_add'    => true, 'by_reference' => false,)); 

}
```

Comment: Read your error message! You have already written "addPedidosmateriales". But you need: "addPedidosmaterial()", "addPedidosmateriale()" or "setPedidosmateriales()".

Comment: It has no sense. If the property is calle pedidosmateriales, the method must be "AddPedidosmateriales".

Comment: I got the solution! Just removing "'by_reference' => false," in my $builder